# iOS Youtube API v3 Subscribe to a youtube channel

Tags: ios, youtube, authorization, google-plus, subscription

I'm using Youtube API v3.0 in an iPhone app, and I have already handled youtube authorization using Google plus API. Now I need to subscribe to a youtube channel following the example here in the link..

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#examples

So in my code..

```
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=%@", API_KEY];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:[AOTube accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet":@{
                                     @"resourceId":@{
                                             @"channelId":CHANNEL_ID,
                                             @"kind":@"youtube#channel"
                                             }
                                     }
                             };

[manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    success(responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    failure(error);

}];
```

I got the following error from the failure block..

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7f8983d5cab0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8983d40ca0> { URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=AIzaSyB1mipmXC8dmXduIJXJ7qt9CxmLlnuc8aw } { status code: 401, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 162;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sun, 04 Jan 2015 22:00:55 GMT";
Expires = "Sun, 04 Jan 2015 22:00:55 GMT";
Server = GSE;
Vary = "Origin, X-Origin";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest\"";
"alternate-protocol" = "443:quic,p=0.02";
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=ewrqDSyB1sfrgdmXduIJfwrgrwgLlnuc8aw, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b0a2022 6572726f 72223a20 7b0a2020 22657272 6f727322 3a205b0a 2020207b 0a202020 2022646f 6d61696e 223a2022 676c6f62 616c222c 0a202020 20227265 61736f6e 223a2022 61757468 4572726f 72222c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 496e7661 6c696420 43726564 656e7469 616c7322 2c0a2020 2020226c 6f636174 696f6e54 79706522 3a202268 65616465 72222c0a 20202020 226c6f63 6174696f 6e223a20 22417574 686f7269 7a617469 6f6e220a 2020207d 0a20205d 2c0a2020 22636f64 65223a20 3430312c 0a202022 6d657373 61676522 3a202249 6e76616c 69642043 72656465 6e746961 6c73220a 207d0a7d 0a>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}
```

I'm sure that there's nothing wrong about API_KEY, CHANNEL_ID, and the access token since I'm already using them in other web services successfully

Comment: Have you solved this problem or not? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have correct to set authorization header field.

Instead of:

```
[requestSerializer setValue:[AOTube accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

use:

```
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [AOTube accessToken]];

[requestSerializer setValue: authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Next correct your request serializer to:

```
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

In authorization process add at least one of the following scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube

sample:

```
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" ];
```

If you are proper signed using Google API you don't must include API key request parameter in URL.

Comment: can you please assist me further? I am getting same error